# Read-only temporal table columns with Linq2DB

Tags: sql-server, linq2db

I have this table with temporal columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profile](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (CreatedDate, UpdatedDate),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Profile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I ran the CLI

```
dotnet linq2db scaffold -i database.json
```

I changed my models to have:

```
[Column(SkipOnUpdate=false, SkipOnInsert=false)]
```

For UpdatedDate and CreatedDate

But when I re-run the linq2db scaffold, it overwrites these attributes, is there a way of preventing that?

Created issue for this here:
https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/3854

Comment: How do you scaffold? T4 or CLI?

Comment: CLI, using dotnet linq2db scaffold -i database.json

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/CLI.html#customization-with-assembly)?

Comment: Yeah - that would work, but I was hoping I would not have to write custom code and just do something like: --ignoreColumnWithName createdDate